# Send HTTP request using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get a JSON object from `http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId=361192737` ([link](http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId=361192737)) using a GET request, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
(function(){
    var xmlHttp;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", 'http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId=361192737', true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    function ProcessRequest(){
        console.log(xmlHttp.responseText); // "" (empty string)
        var respData = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText) || {};
        RemoteEvents = JSON.parse(respData.Description) || null;
    }
})()
```

This is on a Chrome Extension in Development Mode. I'm not very experienced with JavaScript, and even less with HTTP requests. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `onreadystatechange` fires multiple times. you never check what kind of state change it was - many of them do NOT have a responsetext, because the request hasn't reached that stage of the process yet.

Comment: Well did you follow the directions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: Depending on the minimum version you are requiring you can also use the more simple `fetch` api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback " onreadystatechange " will be called multiple times with different " state codes ". 
You have to check the code before trying to get the data to be sure that the request ended.
The code value when it finished is 4, have a look here : 
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

This should work :

```
(function(){
    var xmlHttp;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            console.log(xmlHttp.responseText); // "" (empty string)
            var respData = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText) || {};
            RemoteEvents = JSON.parse(respData.Description) || null;
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", 'http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId=361192737', true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
})();
```

Comment: Works perfectly. It doesn't work with Chrome Extensions, but I'll accept your answer as you're completely right

Comment: @RafDev Is a host permission the matches `api.roblox.com` present in your extension's permissions? (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)

Comment: @apsillers Yep, and I'm using their XMLHttpRequest recommended method, but it still gives me an error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId=36119273. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://lcdggcmeegnliipmgejhcicbnnjkajch' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: @RafDev That is exactly the error message the cross-origin XHR permissions prevent, so you are probably not declaring your permissions correctly. (If your permissions are configured correctly, then cross-origin requests will be allowed in both content scripts and background pages.) But that's probably material for an entirely separate question.

Comment: @RafDev No, that match pattern is exactly the form noted in the first entry under "invalid match patterns" in the link on my first comment (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns); it does not have a path.